# Picking Out Simple Properties from Hierarchical JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

*** Despite the edit to my title by another user, I am seeking a solution that uses JSON.NET's library from C# ***

A reply containing psuedocode is fine! :)

I'm trying to work with hierarchical data provided by a JSON dataset. I'm using C# and JSON.NET. I'm open to using Linq in general and Linq for JSON.NET in particular if it would help; otherwise, using non-Linq C#/JSON.NET is fine.

Ideally, I am trying to accomplish two things elegantly:

1. I want to extract JSON that represents each branch and that branch's own properties--not its child (nested) branch objects (I will explain more in a moment).
2. I want to track the parent node as I create my branch objects.

For further consideration, please refer to the following JSON excerpt:

```
{
  "Branch1": {
    "Prop1A" : "1A",
    "Prop1B" : "1B",
    "Prop1C" : "1C",
    "Branch2" : {
      "Prop2A" : "2A",
      "Prop2B" : "2B",
      "Prop2C" : "2C",
      "Branch3" : {
        "Prop3A" : "3A",
        "Prop3B" : "3B",
        "Prop3C" : "3C"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Related to Goal 1 (from above):**
Given JSON that is composed of nested JSON objects, I want to pick out only the simple (string) properties for each branch. For instance, I would like to extract the JSON for Branch1 that would contain only Prop1A, Prop1B, and Prop1C properties. I would then like to extract the JSON for Branch2 that would contain only Prop2A, Prop2B, and Prop2C properties, etc. I realize that I can represent the entire JSON as a JSON.NET JToken object then iterate through its Children() and look only for JTokenType.Property types, but perhaps there is a more elegant way to quickly pick out just the property types using Linq...? In the end, I would have three separate JSON objects that would look like this:

JSON Object 1:

```
{
  "Prop1A" : "1A",
  "Prop1B" : "1B",
  "Prop1C" : "1C"
}
```

JSON Object 2:

```
{
  "Prop2A" : "2A",
  "Prop2B" : "2B",
  "Prop2C" : "2C"
}
```

JSON Object 3:

{
  "Prop3A" : "3A",
  "Prop3B" : "3B",
  "Prop3C" : "3C"
}

**Related to Goal 2 (from above):**
Ideally, each extracted JSON above would also have a property indicating its parent. Thus, the final JSON objects would look something like this:

```
{
  "Prop1A" : "1A",
  "Prop1B" : "1B",
  "Prop1C" : "1C",
  "Parent" : ""
}
```

And:

```
{
  "Prop2A" : "2A",
  "Prop2B" : "2B",
  "Prop2C" : "2C",
  "Parent" : "Branch1"
}
```

And:

```
{
  "Prop3A" : "3A",
  "Prop3B" : "3B",
  "Prop3C" : "3C",
  "Parent" : "Branch2"
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why isn't `"Branch1"` the parent of the first, `"Prop1A"` object?  That's the immediate parent property name after all.

Comment: Because the JSON in this example means to express a parent-child hierarchical relationship of JSON objects. Object 1 in this case in the parent of Object 2, which is the parent of Object 3. Object 1 maps to Branch1 (a JSON object with no parent and with one child branch--Branch 2); object 2 maps to Branch2 (a JSON object with Branch1 as its parent and with one child branch--Branch 3); object 3 maps to Branch3 (a JSON object with Branch2 as its parent and with no child branch).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm) to find all objects in the JSON hierarchy, then for each object, loop through its [properties](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Properties.htm) and filter out those whose [value](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty_Value.htm) is a [`JValue`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm) primitive.  Thus the following query creates a `List<JObject>` containing the property names and values you require:

```
var root = (JContainer)JToken.Parse(jsonString);

var query1 = from o in root.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>()      // Find objects
             let l = o.Properties().Where(p => p.Value is JValue)       // Select their primitive properties
             where l.Any()                                              // Skip objects with no properties
             select new JObject(l);                                     // And return a JObject

var list1 = query1.ToList();
```

To always skip the root object even if it has primitive properties, use [`JContainer.Descendants()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Descendants.htm).  And if you really only want string-valued properties (rather than primitive properties), you can check the [`JToken.Type`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Type.htm) property:

```
             let l = o.Properties().Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String)       // Select their string-valued properties
```

The query can be enhanced to include a synthetic "Parent" property giving the name of the immediate parent property containing the object, using [`JToken.Ancestors`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Ancestors.htm):

```
var query2 = from o in root.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>()      // Find objects
             let l = o.Properties().Where(p => p.Value is JValue)       // Select their primitive properties
             where l.Any()                                              // Skip objects with no properties
             // Add synthetic "Parent" property
             let l2 = l.Concat(new[] { new JProperty("Parent", o.Ancestors().OfType<JProperty>().Select(a => a.Name).FirstOrDefault() ?? "") })
             select new JObject(l2);                                    // And return a JObject.

var list2 = query2.ToList();
```

However, in your desired output you seem to want the property name of the parent of the object, rather than the property name of the object.  If so, you can do:

```
var query3 = from o in root.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>()      // Find objects
             let l = o.Properties().Where(p => p.Value is JValue)       // Select their primitive properties
             where l.Any()                                              // Skip objects with no properties
             // Add synthetic "Parent" property
             let l2 = l.Concat(new[] { new JProperty("Parent", o.Ancestors().OfType<JProperty>().Skip(1).Select(a => a.Name).FirstOrDefault() ?? "") })
             select new JObject(l2);                                    // And return a JObject.

var list3 = query3.ToList();
```

For the final query, if I do:

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list3, Formatting.Indented));
```

The following output is generated, showing the `JObject` list has the contents you require:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "Prop1A": "1A",
>     "Prop1B": "1B",
>     "Prop1C": "1C",
>     "Parent": ""
>   },
>   {
>     "Prop2A": "2A",
>     "Prop2B": "2B",
>     "Prop2C": "2C",
>     "Parent": "Branch1"
>   },
>   {
>     "Prop3A": "3A",
>     "Prop3B": "3B",
>     "Prop3C": "3C",
>     "Parent": "Branch2"
>   }
> ]
> ```

Note that if the JSON objects themselves have a property named `"Parent"`, the `JObject` constructor may throw a duplicated key exception.

Comment: Appreciated--but need different/separate JSON objects from algorithm, not trying to restructure existing JSON but trying instead to break original JSON into multiple, smaller JSON objects that retain hierarchy through a link to the parent. Please see clarification to original post. Apologies for perhaps not making request clearer. Also, love the DescendantsAndSelf(). Thank up kindly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *retain hierarchy through a link to the parent.*  parent/child relationships in Linq-to-JSON are bidirectional so if the child "links" to the parent then the parent must have a property referring to the child, which is not what you show in your question.  Also, are you simply trying to get a list of `JObject` objects instead of a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Sure-fair q's: Ultimately, these JSON objects are going to end up as C# objects. Branch1 will be an object representing a Windows GUI control container (such as a form control); Branch2 will be a container object inside the form (such as a panel); Branch3 will be a control inside the panel. It's enough for me to know only the control's parent. A list of JObject objects would be fine, where [0] has Branch1, [1] has Branch 2, etc. Thank you.

Comment: @Jazimov - answer was modified to return a list of JObjects

Comment: Splendid! Can't thank you enough! If you can, please provide any reference for mastering Linq for JSON.NET other than the online JSON.NET documentation, which I find very difficult to use/understand...

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here (dbc, your help was spectacular--I learned so much from your examples, including how to leverage JContainer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602932/picking-out-simple-properties-from-hierarchical-json-part-ii